# How would I test controllers in Rhomobile in a BDD style?

Tags: testing, rspec, bdd, rhomobile

I am using the [Rhomobile](http://www.rhomobile.com) framework to develop an application that is supposed to run on different mobile phones. The [tutorial](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/tutorial) mentions how to write tests for the example model: *Person*. In fact, the framework provides a command-line tool `rhogen spec` to generate the dummy tests for the models. How would I go about writing tests for the controller class: *PersonController*? I was thinking of something similar to how one would do it in [Rails](http://www.clarkware.com/blog/2007/09/08/how-would-you-test-this#TestingCont), but rspec is unknown to me, and the methods `post` and `redirect_to` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I too would love a cookbook answer for this sort of setup.

Answer (score 0):

In BDD when you want to specify the behavior of the application (this is what controllers are responsible for) - you would normally aproach that with a StoryBDD framework - use for example [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) . Rspec is SpecBDD and regards a different level of abstraction - it is for specifying how classess communicate with each other and what they do.

You can find many tutorials on [Cucumber's github page](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/tutorials-and-related-blog-posts). [This one](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2009/10/03/getting-started-with-cucumber-rspec-webrat-and-multiruby/) could be helpful